# Table name as field

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to query a table whose name comes from a sub-query?

For example.,

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME IS <SUB_QUERY>>

select * from (
(select distinct(name) from category where id = 3 limit 1) CAT);

INNER QUERY RESULTS --> DEPARTMENT;
```

So it has to fetch from department table.

Using Mysql as DB.

Comment: yep.. just gives the value of inner query. My idea is to eliminate if,else and use a static lookup to query a table based on id dynamically

Comment: You can only do this using prepared statements, where you dynamically create the SQL and then execute it.  You can't do it in a single SQL statement.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm relatively new to prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

In your case it should be:

```
select @name := name from (
(select distinct(name) from category where id = 3 limit 1) CAT);

set  @sqlquery := 'select * from ' . @name ;
prepare qry from @sqlquery ;
execute qry;
deallocate prepare qry;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)
In two words: you can execute sql commands specified in varchar variables which can be produced by concatenation and other stuff.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. Please provide the relevant excerpt from your link as links may go bad.